# Simple JavaScript Backbone.Js tool to highlight multiple search terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, backbone.js, underscore.js

I wrote a simple JavaScript tool to highlight multiple keywords at the same time in some text. It uses different color for each keyword, and also shows the count of matches.

I'm using [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) with the following class structure:

- `App.Model`: the main model, keeping track of:

  - the keywords
  - the words in the text and their count
  - the original text
  - the transformed text with highlighted words
- `App.OriginalTab`, `App.HighlightedTab`: View classes, for showing the original text and the highlighted text, respectively, in tabs
- `App.KeywordView`: a View class, handling the input of new keywords
- `App.Keyword`: a Model class, keeping track of a keyword and its count in the text
- `App.KeywordList`: a Collection class, keeping track of the keywords. Changes to the collection trigger updating the highlighted text
- `App.KeywordsView`: a View class, to render the list of keywords, highlighted using the same color as the highlight in the text, showing the count, and a button to remove from the list

Implementation:

```
var App = window.App = {};

_.templateSettings = { interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g };

App.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        original: '',
        keywords: [],
        words: {},
        highlighted: ''
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('change:original', this.onOriginalUpdated, this);
        this.on('change:keywords', this.onKeywordsUpdated, this);
    },
    updateWords: function () {
        var words = {};
        _.each(this.get('original').split(/\W+/), function (word) {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            words[word] = (words[word] || 0) + 1;
        });
        this.set({words: words});
    },
    updateHighlighted: function () {
        var highlighted = this.escape('original');
        var cnt = 1;
        _.each(this.get('keywords'), function (keyword) {
            var pattern = '\\b' + keyword;
            var cname = 'hlt' + cnt++;
            highlighted = highlighted.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'), '<span class="' + cname + '">' + keyword + '</span>');
        });
        this.set({highlighted: highlighted});
    },
    onOriginalUpdated: function () {
        this.updateWords();
        this.updateHighlighted();
    },
    onKeywordsUpdated: function () {
        this.updateHighlighted();
    },
    getCount: function (word) {
        var pattern = '\\b' + word;
        var matches = this.get('original').match(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'));
        return matches ? matches.length : 0;
    }
});

App.Tab = Backbone.View.extend({
    activate: function () {
        var id = this.$el.attr('id');
        var anchor = $('a[href=#' + id + ']');
        anchor.tab('show');
    }
});

App.OriginalTab = App.Tab.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.text = this.$('.text');
    },
    fieldToFocus: this.$('.text'),
    events: {
        'blur .text': 'onTextChanged'
    },
    onTextChanged: function () {
        this.model.set({original: this.text.val()});
    }
});

jQuery.fn.selectText = function () {
    var element = this[0];
    var range;
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

App.HighlightedTab = App.Tab.extend({
    template: _.template($('#highlighted-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change:highlighted', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        var element = this.$('.highlighted');
        this.$('.select').click(function () {
            element.selectText();
        });
        return this;
    }
});

App.KeywordView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($('#keyword-template').html()),
    events: {
        'dblclick .view': 'edit',
        'click a.destroy': 'clear',
        'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
        'blur .edit': 'close'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.input = this.$('.edit');
        return this;
    },
    edit: function () {
        this.$el.addClass('editing');
        this.input.focus();
    },
    close: function () {
        var value = this.input.val();
        if (!value) {
            this.clear();
        }
        this.model.set({keyword: value});
        this.$el.removeClass('editing');
    },
    updateOnEnter: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            this.close();
        }
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.model.clear();
    }
});

App.Keyword = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            keyword: 'empty keyword...',
            count: 0,
            index: 1
        };
    },
    initialize: function () {
        App.model.on('change:words', this.refreshCount, this);
        this.refreshCount();
    },
    refreshCount: function () {
        var keyword = this.get('keyword');
        this.set({count: App.model.getCount(keyword)});
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.destroy();
    }
});

App.KeywordList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Keyword,
    localStorage: new Store('highlighter-backbone'),
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('add', this.onChange, this);
        this.on('remove', this.onChange, this);
        this.on('reset', this.onChange, this);
    },
    onChange: function () {
        var keywords = this.pluck('keyword');
        App.model.set({keywords: keywords});
        App.highlightedTab.activate();
    }
});

App.KeywordsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#keywords',
    events: {
        'keypress .keyword': 'createOnEnter',
        'click th a.destroy': 'clear'
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.keywords = options.list;
        this.input = this.$('.keyword');
        this.keywords.bind('add', this.add, this);
        this.keywords.bind('reset', this.reset, this);
        this.keywords.fetch();
        if (this.keywords.length) {
            this.keywords.each(this.add);
        }
        else {
            this.create('lorem');
            this.create('ipsum');
            this.create('dolor');
        }
    },
    add: function (keyword) {
        var view = new App.KeywordView({model: keyword});
        this.$('#keyword-list').append(view.render().el);
    },
    reset: function () {
        this.$('#keyword-list').empty();
    },
    createOnEnter: function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this.input.val()) {
            return;
        }
        var keyword = this.input.val();
        this.create(keyword);
        this.input.val('');
    },
    create: function (keyword) {
        var index = this.keywords.length + 1;
        this.keywords.create({keyword: keyword, index: index});
    },
    clear: function () {
        // todo: isn't there a better way?
        var i = 0;
        var maxiter = 10;
        while (true) {
            this.keywords.invoke('destroy');
            if (!this.keywords.length || ++i > maxiter) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});

function onDomReady() {
    App.model = new App.Model();

    App.originalTab = new App.OriginalTab({
        el: $('#original-tab'),
        model: App.model
    });

    App.highlightedTab = new App.HighlightedTab({
        el: $('#highlighted-tab'),
        model: App.model
    });

    App.keywordList = new App.KeywordList();
    App.keywordsView = new App.KeywordsView({
        model: App.model,
        list: App.keywordList
    });

    $('#reset').click(function () {
        App.keywordsView.clear();
        App.originalTab.text.val('');
        App.originalTab.activate();
        App.originalTab.text.focus();
    });

    // other initialization
    App.keywordsView.input.focus();
    App.model.set({original: App.originalTab.text.text()});
}

$(function () {
    onDomReady();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or simpler? Am I using Backbone.js correctly? Can I organize my classes better?

You can see the code in action [here](http://janosgyerik.github.io/highlighter/).

The full source code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/highlighter).

Comment: Please test this scenario: Original Text : `"12"` Tokens to Search : `["1","2"]`. This works as expected. `{<span class="hlt1">1</span> <span class="hlt2">2</span>}` Now try searching with three tokens : `["1","2","span"]` - Here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EOrzh.png

Comment: @anoopPrasad clearly a bug, well spotted, thanks! If you expand on that point, including suggestions of what I did wrong and how it can be better, that could become an answer I would upvote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick note (I'm so sorry I have no chance to read the full code)
please be careful when using reference values (i.e object and arrays) in `defaults`, let me show you one example of how this could be turned into an unexpected behavior:

```
A = Backbone.Model.extend({defaults:{arr: ['a', 'b']}})
a = new A()
a.get('arr').push('c')
a.get('arr')
>> ["a", "b", "c"]
b = new A()
b.get('arr')
>>["a", "b", "c"]
```

This happens because `arr` attributes in both `a` and `b` instances of `Model A` refers to same value which is `arr` array reference in memory so when you are doing `a.get('arr').push('c')` you actually manipulate the `arr` value you referenced when you first declared `defaults` so any next instance of `Model A` will use the new value of `arr` which is `["a", "b", "c"]` I hope this is clear.

One way you could solve this is to check for your `defaults` in `initialize` method instead so it'll create new instance of `arr` whenever there's no one present if we apply this to your `initialize` method:

```
   initialize: function() {
    if (!this.get('keywords')) {
        this.set({
            keywords: new Array()
        });
    }

    if (!this.get('words')) {
        this.set({
            words: new Object()
        });
    }
    this.on('change:original', this.onOriginalUpdated, this);
    this.on('change:keywords', this.onKeywordsUpdated, this);
}
```

Comment: Excellent point! I corrected it by changing to `defaults: function () { ... }` instead of a plain object, and that works well. I do wish you'd read till the end and criticized more ;-)